# Как заставить считать производную, которая берётся при вводе?

Tags: python, математика, python-2.x

Имею:

```
    #Производная
if (value == 10):
    x = input("Введите выражение: ")
    print ("")
    x = Symbol("x")
    y = y.diff(x)
    print ("")
    print ("y")
```

Но увы, не работает:

```
10
Введите выражение: x**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "calc.py", line 159, in <module>
x = input("Введите выражение: ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Как имея различные математ. пакеты для питона 2.7 посчитать производную, которая вводится при запросе? Также это касаемо интеграла..

Comment: Почему input не записывается в переменную?

Comment: @Alex78191, дополнил

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sympy+diff

Comment: @MaxU вся загвоздка в том, чтобы он брал производную от того, что в input вводится, но при вводе, скажем x**2. падает на NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за [подсказку @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%91%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/796160?noredirect=1#comment1256510_796160) - проблема была в использовании `input()` вместо `raw_input()` в Python 2.7.

В Python 2.7 `input()` внутри вызывает `eval(string, globals, locals)` - это видно из `error traceback` и не найдя переменной `xx` - выдает ошибку:

```
In [8]: %paste
input_string = input('Выражение: ')

## -- End pasted text --
Выражение: xx**2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1d395b68d84c> in <module>()
----> 1 input_string = input('Выражение: ')

C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\win_unicode_console\raw_input.pyc in input(prompt)
    111         locals = caller_frame.f_locals
    112
--> 113         return eval(string, globals, locals)
    114
    115

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'xx' is not defined
```

если использовать `raw_input()` - то все отработает и без явного объявления переменной `sympy`:

```
In [3]: %paste
from sympy import diff
input_string = raw_input('Выражение: ')
print(diff(input_string))
## -- End pasted text --
Выражение: xxx**2
2*xxx
```

---

в Python 3.x следуют использовать функцию `input()`, т.к. функция `raw_input()` [Python 2.x] была переименована в `input()` [Python 3.x], а функцию `input()` [Python 2.x] просто удалили из-за неявного использования опасной функции `eval()`...

Соответственно функция `input()` в Python 3.x соответствует функции `raw_input()` в Python 2.x, а аналога функции `input()` из Python 2.x (с вызовом `eval()`) в Python 3.x - нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74308/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu------).