# Почему не считается производная и интеграл если введены 2 разные переменные?

Tags: python, математика, python-2.x, sympy

Вопрос после [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796142/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)

Имеется питон 2.7.12 и эта ошибка при вводе функции с двумя разными переменными: 
   Выражение: x**2-y

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "calc.py", line 159, in <module>
sympy.pprint (sympy.diff(input_string))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1837, in diff
 return Derivative(f, *symbols, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1080, in __new__
must be supplied to differentiate %s''' % expr))
ValueError: 
Since there is more than one variable in the expression, the
variable(s) of differentiation must be supplied to differentiate x**2
- y
```

При таком участке кода:

```
import sympy, sympy.abc
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import symbols
input_string = raw_input('Выражение: ')
print ("")
print ("")
sympy.pprint (sympy.diff(input_string))
```

Почему так? Как решить это недоразумение?

Comment: Надо указать по какой переменной вы хотите дифференцировать - http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html

Comment: @MaxU, а по двум сразу возможно?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Вам не надо программировать производные.

Comment: @Igor, я так не думаю. Мало ли, кто-то ещё кроме меня с подобным столкнётся

Comment: @AndrewGoldman это как, сразу по двум? Полный дифференциал? Или частные производные сначала по одной, потом по другой?

Comment: @D-side, да, полный дифференциал

Comment: Ну, его можно посчитать по определению через частные производные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
In [60]: from sympy.abc import symbols

In [61]: from sympy import diff

In [62]: x,y = symbols('x y')

In [63]: expr = 'x**2-y**2'

In [64]: sum(diff(expr, var) for var in [x,y])
Out[64]: 2*x - 2*y
```

Вариант с тремя переменными:

```
In [83]: %paste
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')

expr = 'x**2 - x*y**2 + sin(y*z**2)'

print(sum(diff(expr, var) for var in [x,y,z]))
## -- End pasted text --
-2*x*y + 2*x - y**2 + 2*y*z*cos(y*z**2) + z**2*cos(y*z**2)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [230]: expr = '2*x - 2*y'

In [231]: sum(integrate(expr, var) for var in [x,y])
Out[231]: x**2 - y**2
```

Comment: только с интегралом такая фишка не прокатила..

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, `sum(integrate(expr, var) for var in [x,y])` - не работает?

Comment: уже заработало. мешала

      sympy.pprint (sympy.Integral(input_string))
для красивого вывода

Comment: работает, но не правильно.. считает не правильно теперь

Comment: @AndrewGoldman потому что вам не сумма интегралов нужна, по всей видимости.

Comment: @d-side, и как быть в  таком случае?

Comment: @AndrewGoldman определиться с тем, что вам нужно, разумеется.